# How to feed the data obtained from rospy.Subscriber data into a variable?

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I have written a sample Subscriber. I want to feed the data that I have obtained from the rospy.Subscriber into another variable, so that I can use it later in the program for processing. At the moment I could see that the Subscriber is functioning as I can see the subscribed values being printed when I use rospy.loginfo() function. Although I donot know how to store this data into another varible. I have tried assigning it  directly to a variable by using assignment operator '=', but I get error.

I have tried writing a callback function with rospy.loginfo to print the position data from the subscribed object. I have subscribed JointState and it containes, header, position, velocity and effort arrays. using rospy.loginfo I can verify that the subscriber is subscribing. But when i tried to assign it directly to a variable, I get an error.

I am displaying loginfo from a call back function as follows

```
def callback(data):
   rospy.loginfo(data.position)
   global listen
    listen = rospy.Subscriber("joint_states", JointState, 
    callback)
    rospy.spin()
```

and this works fine. But when i slightly modify the code to assign the subscribed values, I get following error i.e.

````
   listen1 = rospy.Subscriber("joint_states", JointState, 
   callback=None)
   listen = listen1.position
   #rospy.loginfo(listen)
   print(listen)
   rospy.spin()```

The error is as follows, 
 ```listen = listen1.position
    AttributeError: 'Subscriber' object has no attribute 'position'
````

EDIT:
Here is my node I have defined in my program,

```
    #rospy.loginfo(msg.data)
    global tactile_states
    tactile_states = data.data

def joint_callback(data):
    #rospy.loginfo(data.position)
    global g_joint_states 
    global g_position
    global g_pos1
    g_joint_states = data
    #for i in len(data.position):
        #g_position[i] = data.position[i]
    g_position = data.position
    if len(data.position) > 0:
        print("jointstate more than 0")
        g_pos1 = data.position[0]
    #print(g_position)


def joint_modifier(*args):
    #choice describes what the node is supposed to do whether act as publisher or subscribe to joint states or tactile sensors
    rospy.init_node('joint_listener_publisher', anonymous=True)
    pub1 = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size = 10)
    if(len(args)>1):
        choice = args[0]
        joint_name = args[1]
        position = args[2]
    else:
        choice = args[0]
    if (choice == 1):
        rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        robot_configuration = JointState()
        robot_configuration.header = Header()
        robot_configuration.name = [joint_name]
        robot_configuration.position = [position]
        robot_configuration.velocity = [10]
        robot_configuration.effort = [100]
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            robot_configuration.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
            rospy.loginfo(robot_configuration)
            break
        pub1.publish(robot_configuration)
        rospy.sleep(2)
    if (choice == 2):
        #rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(2), joint_modifier)
        listen = rospy.Subscriber("joint_states", JointState, joint_callback)
        rospy.spin()
    if (choice == 3):
        #rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(2), joint_modifier)
        tactile_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/sr_tactile/touch/ff", Float64, tactile_callback)
        rospy.spin()
```

This is how I am calling the node inside the main body of the program,

```
           joint_modifier(2)
           print("printing g_position")
           print(g_position)#to check the format of g_position
           print("printed g _position")
           leg_1 = Leg_attribute(g_position[0], g_position[1], g_position[2], velocity1 = 10, velocity2 = 10, velocity3 = 10, effort1 = 100, effort2 = 100, effort3 = 100, acceleration=1)
```

When calling this way, the program is stuck at `joint_modifier(2)` as that function has `rospy.spin()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style which you're using is not very standard. I assume you've seen the [example](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node) on ROS wiki, I've modified it to demonstrate standard usage below.

Chiefly, addressing the code you posted, you needed to make `listen` have global scope outside of the callback. This is to store the `data` you want, not the Subscriber object. The rospy.spin() never goes in a callback, only the main node function/section. The subscriber object, `listen1`, which is used infrequently, doesn't return anything, and doesn't store the data it acquires. That is, you need Subscriber() to have a non-None callback.
It's more of a `bind`, giving the `data` to the `callback` instead of returning it from Subscriber. That's why `listen1` [(Subscriber)](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html) has no attribute `position` [(JointState)](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html).

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState

# Subscribers
#     joint_sub (sensor_msgs/JointState): "joint_states"

# This is where you store all your data you recieve
g_joint_states = None
g_positions = None
g_pos1 = None

def timer_callback(event): # Type rospy.TimerEvent
    print('timer_cb (' + str(event.current_real) + '): g_positions is')
    print(str(None) if g_positions is None else str(g_positions))

def joint_callback(data): # data of type JointState
    # Each subscriber gets 1 callback, and the callback either
    # stores information and/or computes something and/or publishes
    # It _does not!_ return anything
    global g_joint_states, g_positions, g_pos1
    rospy.loginfo(data.position)
    g_joint_states = data
    g_positions = data.position
    if len(data.position) > 0:
        g_pos1 = data.position[0]
    print(g_positions)

# In your main function, only! here do you subscribe to topics
def joint_logger_node():
    # Init ROS
    rospy.init_node('joint_logger_node', anonymous=True)

    # Subscribers
    # Each subscriber has the topic, topic type, AND the callback!
    rospy.Subscriber('joint_states', JointState, joint_callback)
    # Rarely need to hold onto the object with a variable: 
    #     joint_sub = rospy.Subscriber(...)
    rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(2), timer_callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    # This is an infinite loop, the only code that gets ran are callbacks
    rospy.spin()
    # NO CODE GOES AFTER THIS, NONE! USE TIMER CALLBACKS!
    # unless you need to clean up resource allocation, close(), etc when program dies

if __name__ == '__main__':
    joint_logger_node()
```

Edit 1:
There seems to be some confusion on what Subscriber(), spin(), and _callback(s) do.
It's a bit obscured in the Python, but there is a master program that manages all nodes, and sending nodes between them. In each node, we register with that master program that the node exists, and what publishers and subscribers it has. By register, it means we tell the master program, "Hey, I want that topic!"; in your case, for your (undeclared) joint_sub Subscriber, "Hey, I want all the `JointState` msgs from the `joint_states` topic!" The master program will, every time it gets (from some publisher somewhere) a new `joint_states` `JointState` msg, send it to that subscriber.
The subscriber handles, deals with, and processes the msg (data) with a *callback*: when(!) I receive a message, run the callback.

So the master program receives a new `joint_states` `JointState` msg from some publisher. Then it, because we registered a subscriber to it, sends it to this node. rospy.spin() is an infinite loop waiting for that data. This is what it does (kinda-mostly):

```
def rospy.spin():
    while rospy.ok():
        for new_msg in get_new_messages from master():
            if I have a subscriber to new_msg:
                my_subscriber.callback(new_msg)
```

rospy.spin() is where your callback, joint_callback (and/or timer_callback, etc) actually get called, and executed. It *only* runs when there is data for it.

More fundamentally, I think because of this confusion, your program structure is flawed; your functions don't do what you think they do. This is how you should make your node.

1. Make your math-portion (all the real non-ros code), the one doing the NN, into a separate module, and make a function to run it.
2. If you only want to run it when you receive data, run it in the callback. If you want to publish the result, publish in the callback.
3. Don't call the main function! The `if __name__ == '__main__': my_main_function()` should be the only place it gets called, and this will call your code. I repeat: the main function, declaring subscribers/publishers/init/timers/parameters, is only run in `if __name__ ...`, and this function runs your code. To have it run your code, place your code in a callback. Timer callbacks are handy for this.

I hope this code sample clarifies:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
import my_nn as nn # nn.run(data)

# Subscribers
#     joint_sub (sensor_msgs/JointState): "joint_states"

# Publishers
#     joint_pub (sensor_msgs/JointState): "target_joint_states"

joint_pub = None

def joint_callback(data): # data of type JointState
    pub_msg = JointState() # Make a new msg to publish results
    pub_msg.header = Header()
    pub_msg.name = data.name
    pub_msg.velocity = [10] * len(data.name)
    pub_msg.effort = [100] * len(data.name)
    # This next line might not be quite right for what you want to do,
    # But basically, run the "real code" on the data, and get the
    # result to publish back out
    pub_msg.position = nn.run(data.position) # Run NN on data, store results
    joint_pub.publish(pub_msg) # Send it when ready!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Init ROS
    rospy.init_node('joint_logger_node', anonymous=True)
    # Subscribers
    rospy.Subscriber('joint_states', JointState, joint_callback)
    # Publishers
    joint_pub = rospy.Publisher('target_joint_states', JointState, queue_size = 10)
    # Spin
    rospy.spin()
    # No more code! This is not a function to call, but its
    # own program! This is an executable! Run your code in
    # a callback!
```

Notice that a python module we design to be a ros node, has *no* functions to be called. It has a defined structure of callbacks and global data shared between them, all initialized and registered in the main function / `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother again, in the sample you have mentioned, what is the data type for g_position, is it an array or an object ? when tried to access it ,i get "NoneType object is not subscriptable". Kindly please help me. Thank you

Comment: If you click on the link `(JointState)`, it shows that JointState.position (`data.position`) is an array of doubles. `g_positions` is just assigned that value in the callback. 
Now, if `g_positions` a NoneType/None, then you haven't received any callbacks yet, it hasn't received any data. You should check if it's None first, and then when it's not, check length and then access your data.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with ros, using c++ isn't a bad option, because it will force you to get the types correct at the beginning, and always know what the variable types are. Type errors are definitely where I also mess up the most.

Comment: Thank you very much. yes I have read that documentation of JointState, although i was not sure about data.position being array because, when I accessed individual element in the array i got this error, as you said it might be caused because it had not received any data , but I was confused about that as well because in the first line of the function callback, we tried to log the data.position and the position values are being displayed on terminal.

Comment: So i did not understand what's causing this ? it must be problem with assigning data.position to g_positions. If you have any preliminary diagnosis where I must look into, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: If we look at the `data` given by the callback of type JointPositions, it has a member `.position`. This _is_ an array, and `data` cannot be `None`. If you got the error trying to use `g_positions` in another callback/function, `g_positions` might be `None` until the first `joint_callback`. 
If the position values, printing/logging `data.position` looks correct, then the problem is how you are handling the data.

Comment: Hello, I have been still struck with this piece of code. I have gone through the subscriber tutorials and I have understood why you did each of these steps. Although I have been having a problem, when I try to call ```g_positions``` at later stages after calling the subscriber, its still returning ```None```. I believe it must contain ```data.position``` values as we have passed on ```g_positions = data.position``` in the callback function.

Comment: But i could see, the command ```print(g_positions)``` is being executed as its printing the position values on the screen. So i am wondering why ```g_position``` storing the ```data.position``` values only when calling the subscriber and once the subscriber node is stopped to do further calculations with the obtained ```g_position```, its value is being rest to ```None```.

Comment: I believe, its because of the type of the ```g_position```, is it that ```g_position``` only stores the ```data.position``` values as long as the node is running and once its stopped, does it get reset back to ```None```. is it true reason ?

Comment: You're half, right, sorry, I made a bad error with this posting. I edited it for future reference. In C++ (I do a little more in/with), this is correct. In Python, within joint_callback, g_joint_states, g_positions, and g_pos1 are all _local_ variables, not referencing the (never set) global ones. You can either wrap in/use in a class, or in a short script like this, using (really) just one global variable, add the line (to the callback) `global g_positions(, g_joint_states, g_pos1)`. This can be elegant enough if designed well; you just have to be explicit when using globals.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it already by declaring them as global. Although the problem still continues, when I try to access ```g_position```, it prints ```None``` instead of the ```data.position``` values. I have also checked the ```JointState``` documentation and the position value is supposed to be ```float64 []```. Although when I try to ```print(g_position)``` inside the callback function, its successfully printing the join angles, but when accessed the ```g_position``` in the next step after calling the subscriber, its returning ```None```.

Comment: can you help me point out what causing this anomaly ? am I using ```None``` type the wrong way ??

Comment: I edited the code again, adding a timer. A timer is usually (beyond other callbacks) how you use the variables. I commented out the print in the joint_callback, and had the timer_callback print the value. I tested it with three terminal applications: one ran `roscore`, one ran `python demo.py` (this), one ran `rostopic pub /joint_states sensor_msgs/JointState "...(stuff)"` (which you don't need to type, should auto complete). 
This all worked for me. I don't know what you're doing... wait a minute

Comment: Don't put your code in the main function. The main function _*EXCLUSIVELY*_ initializes node, declares subscribers, declares publishers, declares timers, reads parameters, and initializes initializers, then spins. It runs no serious code, it runs no code that processes data, it goes into an infinite hang-up state (intentionally), and is never ran again. If you want to process data, periodically, based off of your global data, the most common ros paradigm is to have a callback receive a msg, store the data globally, and have a timer_callback periodically compute/publish stuff based on the data.

Comment: Calling the subscriber, _Initializing it_, does _not_ run the callback. It also won't update (therefore) the global variables, so of course g_positions will still be none - that's the initial value.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by calling subscriber, initializing it does not run the call back ? so calling the function ```joint_logger_node()``` does not run the callback ? 

As mentioned , I have not processed any information after the ```rospy.spin()``` line inside the function body. Although in my program, I need to read the join angles and then use a NN to process them and then again publish the processed output back to the robot.

Comment: So inorder to read the joint angles, when I call ```joint_logger_node()```, its stuck in that ```rospy.spin()``` loop and hence the code is not progressing to next lines where I process these ```g_positions```. I am editing the question with my node function definition and the way I am calling them. Kindly please let me know where I am going wrong as I have been stuck here since a long time and I am approaching my dissertation deadline.

Comment: Don't call joint_logger_node()! Don't call joint_logger_node()! Don't call joint_logger_node()! It's not a function, it doesn't return anything. It's a _main_ function for an executable: _it_ is the one who calls _your_ code, you don't call it. rospy.spin() is supposed to run your code. The code rospy.spin() runs is each of the subscribers and timers. rospy.spin() only runs the subscriber when there is a new message, and the timer when it's the right time. If you want to read from the keyboard, put keyboard-reading-code in a timer; transforming data, either in subscriber or timer. See Edit 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. This so far is the clearest explanation I have got.